# testng.xml not present in project explorer

Tags: eclipse, testng

I'm using eclipse IDE **(Version: Kepler Service Release 2
Build id: 20140224-0627)** & i have installed appropriate testng pluging for that.I've also included testng.jar **(testng-6.8.8)** in project -> properties -> build path -> libraries.

Issue is that i'm not able to find my **testng.xml** file.It might be a very basic issue but i'm facing it.

Following is the view of my project explorer.

[image]

Any help appreciated . . !!

Comment: The strike out part is project confidential.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin or the jar doesn't come with an xml.  You need to create the testng.xml.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run all the tests you've created, then just right click on the project/package/class, scroll all the way down to **TestNG** -> **Create TestNG class**